# Testcontainers JAX-RS integration test not working as expected

Tags: docker, jax-rs, testcontainers

I am recently working on a small app in jax-rs just to get familiar with it, and I am trying to write integration tests using test containers.

The app is deployed on a tomcat container having the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:9-jdk11-openjdk

RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT

COPY target/restapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I have this web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee
                             https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>API Root</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.jchaaban</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>API Root</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have this route:

```
package com.jchaaban.javaeerestapp;


import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/greet")
public class SpeakerApplication extends Application {
    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

which is reachable under the URL: http://localhost:8080/api/greet/hello and it is working fine when I try to test it as following:

```
package com.jchaaban.javaeerestapp.service.persistence.todo;

import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.startupcheck.IndefiniteWaitOneShotStartupCheckStrategy;
import org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.Wait;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;
import org.testcontainers.utility.MountableFile;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
@Testcontainers
public class BasicApplicationIT {

    private static final MountableFile warFile = MountableFile.forHostPath(
            Paths.get("target/rest-app.war").toAbsolutePath(), 511);
    @Container
    private static final GenericContainer microContainer =
            new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("payara/micro:5.2022.2-jdk11"))
                    .withExposedPorts(8080)
                    .withCopyFileToContainer(warFile, "/opt/payara/deployments/app.war")
                    .waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage(".* Payara Micro .* ready in .*\\s", 1))
                    .withCommand("--deploy /opt/payara/deployments/app.war --noCluster --contextRoot /");

    @Test
    public void checkContainerIsRunning(){
        String host = microContainer.getHost();
        Integer port = microContainer.getMappedPort(8080);

        // Construct the correct URL using the host and dynamic port
        String url = "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/api/greet/hello";

        // Perform the test
        given()
                .log().all() // Log the request details
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .when()
                .get(url)
                .then()
                .log().ifValidationFails()
                .log().body()
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Request method: GET
Request URI:    http://localhost:55244/api/speakers/get
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:           <none>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Payara Micro  5.2022.2 #badassmicrofish- Error report</title>
    <style type="text/css">&lt;!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;}  B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--&gt;</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 404 - </h1>
    <hr/>
    <p>
      <b>type</b>
 Status report     </p>
    <p>
      <b>message </b>
    </p>
    <p>
      <b>description </b>
The requested resource is not available.    </p>
    <hr/>
    <h3>Payara Micro  5.2022.2 #badassmicrofish</h3>
  </body>
</html>
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Payara Micro #badassfish
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 1060
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Payara Micro  5.2022.2 #badassmicrofish- Error report</title>
    <style type="text/css">&lt;!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;}  B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--&gt;</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 404 - </h1>
    <hr/>
    <p>
      <b>type</b>
 Status report     </p>
    <p>
      <b>message </b>
    </p>
    <p>
      <b>description </b>
The requested resource is not available.    </p>
    <hr/>
    <h3>Payara Micro  5.2022.2 #badassmicrofish</h3>
  </body>
</html>

java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <404>.
```

Does anyone have expertise in solving this problem? I also attempted to deploy the app on a TomEE and a payara server, but unfortunately, it didn't work for some reason. If anyone could offer some guidance, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I see some stuff doesn't fit, like the path has not been declared, /hello/greet exist but no /api/speakers/get. I think the best thing to do here is sharing a github repository

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've realized that I made a minor error when composing the initial question. After rechecking the test, it appears that the issue persists even when the path is correctly specified.

Comment: either you can see the container log and see why it has not been deployed or can share a github repository to take a look.

Comment: I've uploaded the project to GitLab: https://gitlab.com/jaafar1395/java-ee-rest-app. It's currently running on Tomcat as a temporary solution, but I plan to switch to a server with transaction-type JTA support since Tomcat lacks it. Any feedback on the project would be appreciated, though my primary focus is currently on testcontainers. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The initial code only shares the JAX-RS part but not the persistence stuff related. When packaging a WAR a database is expected for the application to run. So, the integration tests not only need the Application Server but also the database.

```java
static Network network = Network.newNetwork();

@Container
static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:14-alpine")
        .withCopyFileToContainer(
                MountableFile.forClasspathResource("test.sql"),
                "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql")
        .withNetwork(network)
        .withNetworkAliases("postgres");

@Container
static GenericContainer<?> payara = new GenericContainer<>("payara/micro:6.2023.10-jdk17")
        .withExposedPorts(8080)
        .withCopyToContainer(
                Transferable.of(war("payara")), "/opt/payara/deployments/jakarta-tc.war")
        .withCopyFileToContainer(
                MountableFile.forHostPath("target/jdbc-drivers/postgresql-42.3.1.jar"),
                "/opt/databases/drivers/postgresql-42.3.1.jar")
        .withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource("payara/domain.xml", 0777),
                "/opt/payara/config/domain.xml")
        .waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage(".* Payara Micro .* ready in .*\\s", 1))
        .withCommand("--addLibs", "/opt/databases/drivers/postgresql-42.3.1.jar",
                "--deploy", "/opt/payara/deployments/jakarta-tc.war",
                "--domainconfig", "/opt/payara/config/domain.xml")
        .withNetwork(network)
        .dependsOn(postgres);
```

See [this example repository](https://github.com/eddumelendez/jakartaone-livestream-2023).

Comment: I greatly appreciate your providing the example file. I've successfully cloned the project and executed mvn clean install. However, I encountered an issue where the Payara container fails to run on my Mac M1. On the other hand, while the WildFly container does run, I am facing a 404 status code. This issue also arose when I attempted to deploy my own application on a WildFly container. Could you advise if there might be a step I've overlooked or an error in my deployment process?